# MVVMCross - display view inside view

Tags: mvvmcross

I cannot seem to find any simple examples of this.

I have a WPF UI that I wish to display a view as a child control within another view. The `MvxWpfView` inherits from `UserControl` so it should be possible, however I cannot seem to work out how to do the binding.

I get a `BindingExpression` path error, as it cannot find ChildView property in my ParentViewModel.

So how do I bind a view to control content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly it's possible that you just need to add the BViewModel you want displayed on AView as a property on ViewModelA

E.g.

```
public class AViewModel: MvxViewModel
{
    public BViewModel ChildViewModel 
    {
        get;set;//With appropriate property changed notifiers etc.
    }
}
```

Then inside AView you just add a BView, and you can set the datacontext of BView as follows:

```
<UserControl DataContext="{Binding ChildViewModel}"/>
```

However, if you want something more flexible (and you want the presentation handled differently for different platforms) then you will need to use a Custom Presenter

Inside your setup.cs you override CreateViewPresenter:

```
    protected override IMvxWpfViewPresenter CreateViewPresenter(Frame rootFrame)
    {
        return new CustomPresenter(contentControl); 
    }
```

Now create the class CustomPresenter you need to inherit from an existing presenter. You can choose between the one it's probably using already [SimpleWpfPresenter](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Wpf/Views/MvxSimpleWpfViewPresenter.cs) or you might want to go back a bit more to basics and use the [abstract implementation](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Wpf/Views/MvxWpfViewPresenter.cs)

The job of the presenter is to take the viewmodel you have asked it to present, and display it "somehow". Normally that mean identify a matching view, and bind the two together.

In your case what you want to do is take an existing view, and bind a part of it to the second view mode.

This shows how I have done this in WinRT - but the idea is very similar!

```
    public override void Show(MvxViewModelRequest request)
    {
        if (request.ViewModelType == typeof (AddRoomViewModel))
        {
            var loader = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxViewModelLoader>();
            var vm = loader.LoadViewModel(request, new MvxBundle());
            if (_rootFrame.SourcePageType == typeof (HomeView))
            {
                HomeView view = _rootFrame.Content as HomeView;
                view.ShowAddRoom(vm);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            base.Show(request);
        }
    }
```

So what I'm doing is I'm saying if you want me to present `ViewModel` `AddRoom`, and I have a reference to the `HomeView` then I'm going to just pass the `ViewModel` straight to the view.

Inside `HomeView` I simply set the data context, and do any view logic I may need to do (such as making something visible now)

```
internal void ShowAddRoom(Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.IMvxViewModel vm)
{
    AddRoomView.DataContext = vm;
}
```

Hopefully that makes sense! It's well worth putting a breakpoint in the show method of the presenters so you get a feel how they work - they are really simple when you get your head around them, and very powerful.

Comment: That's a lot more complex than I thought it would be. Thanks for that, it might take me a while to process it all, and I am sure I will have some more questions about the reply but it looks good so far!

Comment: The simple adding of the view model, and binding as DataContext works for now. I will revisit the custom view presenter in the near future when I nail down the final layouts a bit more.