# MvvmCross: View inside another View (or the equivalent to a CaliburnMicro Conductor)

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, view, mvvmcross

I am pretty new to MvvmCross and the mvvm pattern in general, so I started a small learning project and immidiatly ran into a wall. I based my application on the idea of having a **MainView** which contains a standard `Menu` and a child `MvxWpfView`. This **ChildView** should be a simple **ReadMeView** first, but on user input it should switch to an other **View** (the one with actual data on it). I already found a few articles about this issue but none of them worked or i wasn't able to follow.
**My setup**:

- Core Library (.NET Standard 2.0)
- Wpf app (.NET Core 3.1)

This is my **MainViewModel** with [this users solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23797667/mvvmcross-display-view-inside-view) still implemented:

```
using MvvmCross.Commands;
using MvvmCross.ViewModels;

namespace puRGE.Core.ViewModels
{
    public class MainViewModel : MvxViewModel
    {
        #region Fields -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        private HomeViewModel m_homeViewModel = new HomeViewModel();
        #endregion ------------------------------------------------------------------------ Fields endregion


        #region Properties ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        public HomeViewModel Home {
            get => m_homeViewModel;
            set => SetProperty(ref m_homeViewModel, value);
        }
        #endregion -------------------------------------------------------------------- Properties endregion


        #region Constructors -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        public MainViewModel() { }
        #endregion ------------------------------------------------------------------ Constructors endregion


        #region Public methods -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        public override void Prepare()
        {
            Home = new HomeViewModel();
        }
        #endregion ---------------------------------------------------------------- Public methods endregion
    }
}
```

This is the xaml part located inside my **MainView** (still part of [this users solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23797667/mvvmcross-display-view-inside-view)):

```
<Menu>
    <!-- Some MenuItems -->
</Menu>
<UserControl DataContext="{Binding Home, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

**Vision VS. Reality**
[image of what I am trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jF5aW.png)
I also tried using the `MvxContentPresentation` attribute, but to be honest I lost myself somewhere in the [MvvmCross Documentation](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/) and at this point I am almost stepping on my eye bags.

```
<local:HomeView/>
```

This doesn't work either. `Binding`s stop working this way even when the properties value get's set inside the `ViewModel`s `Prepare()`method. I guess calling the View like this breaks some chain of events or something.
***How do I place a View inside my MainView? Is this Child then able to navigate to another View and vice versa (following the Navigation Documentation)?***
**Edit_01102020:**
A general Mvvm approach doesn't seem to work so far.
**Edit_02102020:**
Home can now navigate to SomeOtherViewModel and back. Still no clue how to contain this in my MainView.

Comment: Use a `ContentControl` that binds to the `Home` property and then set `Home` to whatever view model you want to display the view for in the `ContentControl`?

Comment: Like this `<ContentControl Content="{Binding Home}"/>` ?! Already tried ... it doesn't work. It only displays this: MyProjectName.Core.ViewModels.HomeViewModel inside the white part of the window.

Comment: That's because you haven't specified a `DataTemplate` for the view model.

Comment: Can you be more specific with what do you mean by specifying a `DataTemplate`?

Answer (score 2):

In your `MainView.xaml`:

```xml
<Menu>
    <!-- Some MenuItems -->
</Menu>
<UserControl DataContext="{Binding Home}">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:ModelAViewModel}">
            <local:ModelAView />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:ModelBViewModel}">
            <local:ModelBView />
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" />
</UserControl>
```

Remember to Notify your changes in your `HomeViewModel`:

```cs
public void ActivateModelAViewModel()
{
    HomeViewModel = Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<ModelAViewModel>();
    //In your HomeViewModel property:
    //RaisePropertyChanged(() => HomeViewModel);
}

public void ActivateModelBViewModel()
{
    HomeViewModel = Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<ModelBViewModel>();
    //In your HomeViewModel property:
    //RaisePropertyChanged(() => HomeViewModel);
}
```

Comment: New to mvvmcross, is there a prerequisite before using Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve? I get this error "MvvmCross.Exceptions.MvxIoCResolveException: 'Failed to resolve type..."

Answer (score 0):

I have also found that the following alternatives also do the job (except for the first one, commented out):

```xml
<StackPanel>
    <!--<TextBlock FontWeight="Bold">1. ContentPresenter - DataContext</TextBlock>
    <ContentPresenter DataContext="{Binding ActiveViewModel}">
        <ContentPresenter.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:WorkWeekViewModel}">
                <local:WorkWeekView />
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:WorkViewModel}">
                <local:WorkView />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ContentPresenter.Resources>
    </ContentPresenter>-->

    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold">2. ContentPresenter - Content</TextBlock>
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding ActiveViewModel}" >
        <ContentPresenter.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:WorkWeekViewModel}">
                <local:WorkWeekView />
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:WorkViewModel}">
                <local:WorkView />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ContentPresenter.Resources>
    </ContentPresenter>

    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold">3. ContentControl - DataContext</TextBlock>
    <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding ActiveViewModel}">
        <ContentControl.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:WorkWeekViewModel}">
                <local:WorkWeekView />
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:WorkViewModel}">
                <local:WorkView />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ContentControl.Resources>
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" />
    </ContentControl>

    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold">4. ContentControl - Content</TextBlock>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding ActiveViewModel}">
        <ContentControl.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:WorkWeekViewModel}">
                <local:WorkWeekView />
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:WorkViewModel}">
                <local:WorkView />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ContentControl.Resources>
    </ContentControl>

    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold">5. UserControl - DataContext</TextBlock>
    <UserControl DataContext="{Binding ActiveViewModel}">
        <UserControl.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:WorkWeekViewModel}">
                <local:WorkWeekView />
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:WorkViewModel}">
                <local:WorkView />
            </DataTemplate>
        </UserControl.Resources>
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" />
    </UserControl>

    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold">6. UserControl - Content</TextBlock>
    <UserControl Content="{Binding ActiveViewModel}">
        <UserControl.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:WorkWeekViewModel}">
                <local:WorkWeekView />
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:WorkViewModel}">
                <local:WorkView />
            </DataTemplate>
        </UserControl.Resources>
    </UserControl>

    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold">7. MvxWpfView - DataContext</TextBlock>
    <views:MvxWpfView DataContext="{Binding ActiveViewModel}">
        <views:MvxWpfView.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:WorkWeekViewModel}">
                <local:WorkWeekView />
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:WorkViewModel}">
                <local:WorkView />
            </DataTemplate>
        </views:MvxWpfView.Resources>
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" />
    </views:MvxWpfView>

    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold">8. MvxWpfView - Content</TextBlock>
    <views:MvxWpfView Content="{Binding ActiveViewModel}">
        <views:MvxWpfView.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:WorkWeekViewModel}">
                <local:WorkWeekView />
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:WorkViewModel}">
                <local:WorkView />
            </DataTemplate>
        </views:MvxWpfView.Resources>
    </views:MvxWpfView>
</StackPanel>
```

Some are just inherited from the others, eg. `MvxWpfView : UserControl`; `UserControl : ContentControl`, but not sure about `ContentPresenter`, which needs not to have the child `<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" />` inside (since it is itself a `ContentPresenter`).

In my case `ActiveViewModel`, `WorkWeekViewModel` and `WorkViewModel` are instances of `MvxViewModel`; `WorkWeekView` and `WorkView` are instances of `MvxWpfView`.