# MvvmCross Wpf View with Sub View

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvmcross

I have a working program in Caliburn Micro but am moving over to MvvmCross.  What I have working in Caliburn is a ShellView (Parent) that displays my navigation buttons and a cart.  On that view, there is another view which is my selection of the navigation buttons, let's call it ActiveView (the view changes, in Caliburn it was ActiveItem() to change the view).

In MvvmCross, I cannot get this same functionality to work.  After 3 days of searching and reading, I need help.  Here is the image of the program, Blue outline is ShellView, inside of it Red outline is ActiveView.
[image]
What I get with MvvmCross is the ShellView, with no ActiveView.  So the parent works, but no child is displayed.  I have created a few other MvvmCross apps but they contain no navigation.

I have 2 Code Versions, First works but creates a second Window.  Second keeps a single Window, but does not navigate.  I need a single window with navigation.  I feel I have a core misunderstanding and cannot find a source that explains it.

**First Sample**  Works, but creates 2 Windows.  An empty window (from MainWindow.xaml) and a second from ShellView.  My assumption for 2 Windows opening when app is ran, is MainWindow being a window, and ShellView also being set to Window in xaml and cs.
Based on MvvmCross Playground.Wpf

```
   <views:MvxWindow 
    x:Class="MvxKioskMtg.Wpf.Views.ShellView"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MvvmCross.Platforms.Wpf.Views;assembly=MvvmCross.Platforms.Wpf"
    xmlns:mvx="clr-namespace:MvvmCross.Platforms.Wpf.Binding;assembly=MvvmCross.Platforms.Wpf"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MvxKioskMtg.Wpf.Views"
    mc:Ignorable="d" 
    d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
        Background="#3d3d3d"
    >
    <views:MvxWindow.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid DataContext="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Button Content="Welcome"  Command="{Binding ShowWindowChildCommand1}" Grid.Column="0"/>
                    <Button Content="Checkout" Command="{Binding ShowWindowChildCommand2}" Grid.Column="1"/>
                </Grid>
                <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" Grid.Row="1" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
        
    </views:MvxWindow.ContentTemplate>
</views:MvxWindow>
```

ShellView.xaml.cs

```
    public partial class ShellView : MvxWindow
    {
        public ShellView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

**Second Version**  Layout looks correct, but no navigation.  Click buttons has no effect.  Adding break point to the Command that changes views and it is never reached.

XAML changed from MvxWindow to MvxWpfView in 4 places, otherwise same as First Version.

```
<views:MvxWpfView
   <views:MvxWpfView.ContentTemplate>
   </views:MvxWpfView.ContentTemplate>
</views:MvxWpfView>
```

ShellView.xaml.cs

```
    public partial class ShellView : MvxWpfView 
    {
        public ShellView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

In the XAML, if I update the DataContect to AncestorType={x:Type views:MvxWpfView} from Window, it does update the View, but the entire View.  Not the ContentPresenter space.  So I lose my navigation buttons.

Which of these methods is correct, and what am I doing incorrect?  Am I totally off base?  Thank you for any help and guidance you can provide.  I'll happily read any sources.

Comment: Please look at the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64739282/486564